# VSCode (Code Helper) JS CPU usage spikes whenever I make any edit in editor

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, next.js, javascript-intellisense

(M2 MacBook Air 16GB, VSCode 1.76.0, macOS 13.2.1)

I'm working in a NextJS project in VSCode, and have been experiencing annoying and disruptive issues all of the time, when the JS/TS Language Features extension is enabled.

With this issue, whenever I make an edit in a JS file, Code Helper's CPU usage spikes, to perhaps 70-100% and with it CPU temperatures. Even actions as simple as literally typing a comma cause my temps to rise from their stable 30-35C to over 50C. This subsequently causes battery drain, simply from typing characters, nothing complex, which is very disruptive.

So far I have tried disabling the JS/TS Language Features extension (which stops the CPU spikes, but essentially turns VSCode into a colourful TextEdit), as well as setting TS disable auto type acquisition to true, to no luck. My `jsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.json` are not present, as per default.

Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Comment: You can open the VS Code devtools with `Developer: Toggle Developer Tools` and getting an execution trace (See the performance tab). Tell us what you find. Does it happen consistently? (Ex. does it still happen if you restart VS Code or restart your computer?) Do you have any antivirus that could be scanning filesystem changes?

Comment: Actually, you might be running into a common issue: On apple.stackexchange.com: [VS Code - Code Helper process using more than 100% CPU on macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/351761/479746). On VS Code's GitHub: [Code Helper (Renderer) uses 100% of CPU in background but nothing is open #101555](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/101555)

Comment: In my case it's not an issue with Code Helper hogging CPU while in the background, it's an issue whereby CPU usage spikes when I'm actively making edits; when I'm triggering the built-in JS/TS features. Any ideas on how to make the built-in JS/TS features less resource-intensive? Quite a large Next project

Comment: @user it appears that the built-in TS server is behind the high CPU usage spikes, as can be seen by following the instructions of the first answer from the Ask Different link. Any ideas on how to action on this?

Comment: no sorry⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: I've just been facing the same issue :( Yep, the only way I could solve it was searching for builtins (in Extensions), and disabling the TypeScript and JavaScript extension. With that extension, any edit to a large JavaScript file causes the CPU to spike. Confirmed it is that using `ps aux | grep id`. Sigh.